# How do I read keyboard input in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directx-11

Here is my attempt of moving a simple triangle drawn with DirectX 11 in C++:

```
int DrawAndMovePlayer(Renderer renderer)
{
    Triangle triangle1(renderer);
    float p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6;
    float x, y;
    x = 0.0f;
    y = 0.0f;

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x58))
    {
        x = 1.0f;
    }

    // Top
    p1 = x + 0.0f;
    p2 = y + 0.05f;

    // Bottom Right
    p3 = x + 0.05f;
    p4 = y - 0.05f;

    // Top
    p5 = x - 0.05f;
    p6 = y - 0.05f;

    // Triangle triangle2(renderer);
    triangle1.draw(renderer, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6);

    //triangle2.draw(renderer, -0.5f);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the `getch()` function and the `GetAsyncKeyState()` function. However, the triangle never changes its position. The triangle is drawn around a center point (`x`, `y`).

Comment: Is the triangle really not moving? Moving distance 1 may be too small to see.

Comment: The LSB of return value of [function `GetAsyncKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has another information, so you should use `GetAsyncKeyState(0x58) & 0x8000` to see if the key is pressed.

Comment: You might consider using the ``Keyboard`` class in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK). See the [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Mouse-and-keyboard-input).

Answer (score 0):

I find the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `GetAsyncKeyState` a bit confusing. I think that [this forum post](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/128459/) gives a better explanation on how `GetAsyncKeyState` works:

> GetAsyncKeyState returns a 16-bit signed value. The **high bit** is set when the current real-time state of the key indicates that it is being held down.
>
> The **low bit** is set when the key has transitioned from a released to a pressed state (like when the key is first pressed). Though the MSDN documentation indicates this is not reliable.
>
> The value of all other bits should be assumed to be "undefined" and you should discard them. I would not recommend assuming they are 0 because they might not be a in a future version.
>
> That said... you should NOT look for absolute return values. IE: checking for -32767 is wrong. Instead, you should mask out the bit you're interested in:
>
> ```
> if(GetAsyncKeyState(x) & 0x8000)
> {
>     // high bit is set.  Key is currently held down.
> }
> if(GetAsyncKeyState(x) & 0x0001)
> {
>     // low bit is set.  Key just transitioned from released to pressed.
> }
> ```

So, this recommendation matches that one given by @MikeCAT in the comments: You should use `GetAsyncKeyState(0x58) & 0x8000` to see if the <kbd>X</kbd> key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! It took me a while to figure this one out on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, but here it is:

```
MSG message;
message.message = WM_NULL;
while (message.message != WM_QUIT) {
    while (PeekMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) { // Make a class file for this or something
                                                           // so when it's HUGE it won't be obtrusive...
                                                           // I mean REALLY.
        if (message.message == WM_KEYDOWN) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x51) == 0x0001); {
                OutputDebugString("key pressed \n");
                pressed = true;
            }
        }
        if (message.message == WM_KEYUP) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x51) != 0x0000); {
                OutputDebugString("key unpressed");
                pressed = false;
            }
        }
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }`
```

The key in question here being 'q' or [virtual key code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) 0x51. And this is all after you create a window, and set things up. If you want the complete code, please comment, or contact me.

Comment: check that, those if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x51) != 0x0000) statements always return true... still working on it

Answer (score 0):

Some more working current code, Visual Studio 2017:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK myModalessWindow(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CHAR: // Case sensitive
            if ((char)wParam == 'A')
                Beep(2000, 250);
            if ((char)wParam == 'b')
                Beep(2000, 250);
        break;

        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            {
                if (GetKeyState('A') & 0x8000 /* Check if high-order bit is set (1 << 15)*/)
                    Beep(2000, 250);

                if (wParam == 'S') // Not case sensitive.
                    Beep(2000, 250);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```